# PointToScreen causing my sub to crash without exception VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a control (an overloaded button) on a form that I am trying to get the screen coordinates of.
I have a device that gives me screen coordinates, without using the cursor position (quite important)
said device raises an event when the coordinates have updated and passes the update to the subscriber (handler).

```
public event UpdateRecived(byval Update as point)
```

The button on the form has a handler that is subscribed to this event that triggers a private sub in the button "handleUpdate()"

In the sub I use PointToScreen to get current drawing point of the button:

```
Private Sub handleNewPacket(ByVal UpdatedCoords As Point)
consol.writeline("UpdateCoords Event Handler Called")
screenPos = Me.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
console.writeline(screenPos.tostring)
End Sub
```

this is the strange part
I get the console output "UpdateCoords Event Handler Called" 
but I don't get the screenPos.tostring output?

if I put a break point in the secound line in the sub is executed but the 3rd line is not.. and there is no exception thrown ?

any ideas?

I have run the same code in a test enviroment with the mouse generating coordinates from a timer and it works fine but when I add the button to the form in the live project the event triggers but the line with pointToScreen in seems to crash without exception?

Comment: Add a try/catch block around `Me.PointToScreen` and see that catches any exception

Comment: There's an exception, it is not valid to call PointToScreen() from a worker thread, your code just doesn't make the debugger stop on it.  Use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions to see this go wrong.  Tens of thousands of Google hits tell you what to do about it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I addded a try catch it then executes the next line but still error

Comment: @DavidHenderson Which means exception is thrown. Refer Hans's comment above and see you'll get a `InvalidOperationException`. Then it is a matter of using a search engine to how to fix it

Comment: @HansPassant I have created a delegate sub in my form and invoked it which seems to resolve the cross-thread error but now i'm getting objectDisposedException.. any ideas ?